# How to remove the bracket in strings like "(2003)" using ultraedit and regular expressions?

Tags: regex, ultraedit

I am going the remove the bracket for strings like "(1978)", "(2003)" in ultraedit. Actually I know how to locate these strings using a regular expression:`\(\d{4}\)`, but I don't know how to remove the bracket. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: install perl on your system, and execute this: perl -pi -e 's!\(\d+\)!$1/g' filename

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find following pattern:

```
\((\d{4})\)
```

and replace that with:

```
^1
```

See [Regular expression for Ultraedit](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/regular_expressions.html)

> ^1
>
> Numerical reference to tagged expressions. Text matched with tagged
>   expressions may be used in Replace commands with this format.

`^1` corresponds to `\1` or `$1` (backreference) in other regular expression engines.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to work it out with your suggestion, but it seems you are using the `perl engine` in ultraedit? And I used `$1` rather than `^1`. All in all, really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to define a capture group in your regular expression like this:

```
\((\d{4})\)
```

Note the unescaped parentheses. You can then use the captured text in the replacement string using `\1` or `$1`. I'm not sure which of those two UltraEdit uses; try them both and see what works.